# Detect tab changes with Ionic React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I've seen this question asked a couple times but I still haven't been able to get it to work. I have a tab bar set up like this:

```
<IonFooter class="swipeable-pages-footer">
    <div className="dot-indicator">
        {
            this.props.pages.map((p, i) => (
                <IonIcon icon={i === index ? ellipse : ellipseOutline} style={{ "transform": "scale(0.6)" }} key={i}></IonIcon>
            ))
        }
    </div>
    <IonToolbar class="swipeable-pages-footer-toolbar">
        <IonTabs>
            <IonRouterOutlet >
            </IonRouterOutlet>

            <IonTabBar slot="bottom" class="swipeable-tab-bar" tabIndex={index}>
                {
                    this.props.tabs.map((t, i) => (
                        <IonTabButton key={i} tab={t.tabName} href={t.tabName} class={"swipeable-tabs-tab-button " + t.tabName} selected={i === index ? true : false} disabled={t?.disabled}>
                            <IonIcon class="swipeable-tabs-tab-icon" icon={t?.icon}></IonIcon>
                            <IonLabel class="swipeable-tabs-tab-label">{t.label}</IonLabel>
                        </IonTabButton>
                    ))
                }
            </IonTabBar>
        </IonTabs>
    </IonToolbar>
</IonFooter>
```

When a tab is changed, I need to call a function called `handleChange`. Originally I was doing this by adding an `onIonTabsDidChange` to the `IonTabs` component. Only just now have I noticed that produces this error:

```
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onIonTabsDidChange`. It will be ignored.
```

It calls the function once and no more (not even on a tab change). I found one github issue on this and someone said to move `onIonTabsDidChange` to the `IonTabBar` instead. Doing so does nothing - it still doesn't call the function on tab change.

Looking at the documentation for IonTabs **and** just plain google searching for `onIonTabsDidChange` there is nothing on `onIonTabsDidChange`, only `ionTabsDidChange` (without the 'on'). However using trying to use this on both `IonTabs` and `IonTabBar` produce a similar error to each other of:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; ionTabsDidChange: (e: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<IonTabs> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Property 'ionTabsDidChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<IonTabs> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'. Did you mean '"onIonTabsDidChange"'?
```

As you can seem, it's even asking me if I meant `onIonTabsDidChange`. Even hovering over `IonTabBar` shows that it should be `onIonTabsDidChange`:

```
(alias) const IonTabBar: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<LocalJSX.IonTabBar & IonicReactProps & {
    onIonTabsDidChange?: (event: CustomEvent<{
        tab: string;
    }>) => void;
    onIonTabsWillChange?: (event: CustomEvent<{
        tab: string;
    }>) => void;
    slot?: "bottom" | "top" | undefined;
    style?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
} & Pick<React.HTMLAttributes<...>, "children" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & React.RefAttributes<...>>
import IonTabBar
```

This is where I'm stuck. Two places are telling me it should be `ionTabsDidChange`. Two places are saying it should be `onIonTabsDidChange` yet no matter what I use it's still not fired when the tabs change.

Comment: do you have a small sample project in stackblitz or code sandbox?

Comment: Never mind, it seems to be working now. I still get the error saying `onIonTabsDidChange` will be ignore but the event is now firing.